# How to Save Copies from a Master Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

The above picture is a simplified example of what I wish to achieve. Essentially, I need a macro that will go through column A, paste into cell C2, and then save a copy of the workbook. Thus, the end result will be "Type1.xlsm", "Type2.xlsm", etc. **At the end of each macro run, the link to the external sheet is broken.**

The issue that I am running into is that every time I save a copy of the master workbook, there is no way for the macro to go back to the original workbook. I need some way in which I can recursively call the macro.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub test()
   For i = 1 To 5
   If Not Range("B" & i).Value = "X" Then
       Range("C2").Value = Range("A" & i).Value
       Calculate 'updates the formula
       Range("B" & i).Value = "X" 'update the check
       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("A" & i).Value
       ActiveWorkbook.Close 
       'INSERT CODE TO BREAK THE EXTERNAL LINK
       'At this point, how do I refer back to the original workbook?
   End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

This is what the output should be:

[image]

And an example of what "Type4.xlsm" should be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be enough to do it. You can create an object variable pointing to the relevant sheet in the master file (may not be the first). The file containing the code can be referred to as ThisWorkbook.

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

For i = 1 To 5
    If Not ws.Range("B" & i).Value = "X" Then
        ws.Range("C2").Value = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
        Calculate 'updates the formula
        ws.Range("B" & i).Value = "X" 'update the check
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ws.Range("A" & i).Value
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        'At this point, how do I refer back to the original workbook?
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response! I tried this out, but it only goes through the loop once - it creates "Type1.xlsm", but doesn't continue to create the rest. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looking at this again, I'm not sure why any amendment is needed. Once you close the copied workbook do you not just have the single file open containing the code? Are there any other files? Is the code definitely in the master file?

Comment: I am possibly not seeing the wood for the trees. Do you have an original file and a master file? I think perhaps the SaveCopyAs referred to below should be enough. That said, it's a good idea to add workbook/sheet references to your variables.

Comment: Hi SJR, thanks a bunch for your comments! I think something that I didn't mention in the original post is that the formula that exists in the workbook is broken after each macro run. Thus, I can't do a SaveCopyAs -- the link would still be incorrect.

Comment: OK, can you clarify the questions in my comment above? Where does this formula point to - I don't see why that should be broken?

Comment: my apologies - it might be slightly unclear from my example, and I can't reveal the actual workbook due to the fact that it contains sensitive information. So the example might not be the most useful, but the idea is there -- that the master file contains a variety of workbook links, and when a separate macro runs, causes the links to be broken. Each time the macro runs, the links are changed

Comment: I don't understand why the link is broken - there is nothing in your code which has anything to do with it. The SaveCopyAs should just save a copy of your file and should not affect the link at all.

Comment: I decided to create another question. My apologies about this post; I think I was unclear and it was hard to describe what is going on without revealing sensitive information. You can find the updated question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491880/creating-copies-from-a-master-workbook-using-vba. Hopefully this one makes more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [SaveCopyAs()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835014.aspx) method

```
Sub test()
    For i = 1 To 5
        If Not Range("B" & i).Value = "X" Then
            Range("C2").Value = Range("A" & i).Value
            Calculate 'updates the formula
            Range("B" & i).Value = "X" 'update the check
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Range("A" & i).Value

            'At this point, your active workbook and worksheet are still the "original" ones
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I try running the code you wrote, yet the SaveCopyAs() method doesn't seem to create any workbooks. I can't find where they are saved. Any tips?

Comment: Not by any PC so can't answer you properly, but try searching it in the same folder of the macro file. Or give it a full path like you can see in the linked documentation example

Comment: @WilliamMa You just need to give a path to `SaveCopyAs` something like  `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\MyFolder\" & Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsm"` or you can use `ActiveWorkbook.Path` to use the same folder.

Comment: @WilliamMa, did you get through it?

Comment: "it didn't work " is actually as sad as it is too little descriptive! What didn't work exactly?

Comment: I decided to create another question. My apologies about this post; I think I was unclear and it was hard to describe what is going on without revealing sensitive information. You can find the updated question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491880/creating-copies-from-a-master-workbook-using-vba. Hopefully this one makes more sense. Thank you!

Comment: I see. You can make as many question as you like, but you should close them all appropriately. I mean if my answer solves the very issue you actually posted here (i.e. _"The issue that I am running into is that every time I save a copy of the master workbook, there is no way for the macro to go back to the original workbook"_) you should accept it. While new issues, which may well arise in the meanwhile, must be posted in a new question, as you already correctly did. thank you!