# Creating Copies from a Master Workbook using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have two files, one the file in which I want to run the macro in and another external file.

Within the file that the macro is running in (henceforth the "master" file), there is something that looks like this:

[image]

The code that I have so far is this:

```
Sub test()
For i = 1 To 3
    If Not Range("B" & i).Value = "X" Then

        Range("C2").Value = Range("A" & i).Value
        Calculate 'updates the formula
        Range("B" & i).Value = "X" 'update the check

        Range("D2").Copy 'this is the tricky part - this is what is needed. The formula links needs to be broken so that only the values remain
        Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\n0269777\Desktop\" & Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsm" 'the problem with SaveCopyAs is that the formula originally is now overwritten.
        'thus I need some way to refer back to the 'master' workbook, the one where the formula has not yet been overwritten

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

What I want to achieve is that the macro will loop through and check to see if a workbook has been created with the names in column A. Then, it will update the value in "C2". Finally, a copy is saved -- **and the formula is overwriten to its value, rather than remain a formula**. This is the difficulty in that I cannot simply save a copy of the workbook -- the formula would have been overwritten after the run of the macro.

This is what happens in Type3.xlsm after running the macro. As you can see, the value in "D2" is 1, whereas it should be 3.

[image]

I have also considered this method:

```
Sub test2()
For i = 1 To 3
    If Not Range("B" & i).Value = "X" Then

        Range("C2").Value = Range("A" & i).Value
        Calculate 'updates the formula
        Range("B" & i).Value = "X" 'update the check

        Set wboor = ActiveWorkbook
        fileaddress = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name

        Range("D2").Copy 'this is the tricky part - this is what is needed. The formula links needs to be broken so that only the values remain
        Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wboor.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\n0269777\Desktop\" & Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsm" 'Perhaps I can save a copy first? Then close the workbook, so the formula is preserved
        wboor.Close
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=fileaddress 'but then, how do I call the original file, and then loop the macro to run again?

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do your saved copied need to have the macros also, or could they be just empty sheets with the copied data values instead of formulas?

Comment: @cyberponk, the saved copies do not need to have the macros, as long as the copied data values are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it was necessary to start a new question, but anyway try this.

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook, s As String, i As Long

For i = 1 To 3
    If Not Range("B" & i).Value = "X" Then
        Range("C2").Value = Range("A" & i).Value
        Calculate 'updates the formula
        Range("B" & i).Value = "X" 'update the check
        s = "C:\Users\n0269777\Desktop\" & Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsm"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs s
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(s)
        wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
        wb.Close True
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad we got there in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could save a copy of the formula, and put it back into the workbook each time. ie:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Dim formulaText As String
    formulaText = .Range("D2").Formula
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 3
        If Not .Range("B" & i).Value = "X" Then
            .Range("C2").Value = Range("A" & i).Value
            Calculate 'updates the formula
            .Range("B" & i).Value = "X" 'update the check

            .Range("D2").Copy
            .Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs  "C:\Users\n0269777\Desktop\" & Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsm" 
            .Range("D2").Formula = formulaText
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I like this idea, but is it practical if you have thousands of formulas? I oversimplified what I was doing in this example

Comment: If you read the formulae in and out of an array then it should be very quick.